# Java - creating text adventure with no objects at all,

Tags: java

This is my first time here, i am very new to programming, i have been learning java for 2 weeks now and i only know some basics, so i decided to test my knowledge by doing a simple text adventure game without using objects as i haven't got the grip of that yet. I will just keep printing the story and describing the situation, and accepting player choices to go on.
But i am having a problem with my code that i don't know how to repeat a question if the user entered an invalid choice, i tried couple of ways but the program either ends or gives me infinite loop, i need some help ,please.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class The_Crime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome Stranger, Please Enter Your Name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome" + name);       
        Street street = new Street();

        System.out.println("You are now in the street with a dead body on the floor drowned in blood \n there is a building right ahead of you\n What would you like to do?");
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        while(true) {
            if(choice.equals("enter building")) {
                System.out.println("You have entered the empty building");     
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are now in the street with a dead body lying around drawned in blood \n there is a building right infront of you\n What would you like to do?");
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

Comment: You do realize `System`, `Scanner`, `String`, `Street` are all objects

Comment: It is 100% impossible to not use objects in java

Comment: heyy just use primitive types!! you are cheating in your own gameeeee!!

Comment: @chancea Classes, actually. I know I'm being pedantic.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and in fact, seen as these are basic concepts to programming, you might like to take a look at [Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) as well

Comment: Why would you use a Object Oriented Language if you dont want to use objects at all! Use a procedural language like C.

Comment: Why does this question have -5 ?!!

Comment: The response to this question is frustrating. OP is "very new to programming", i.e. "two weeks", and is downvoted for not knowing what objects are yet? Comments like, "Use a procedural language like C," are basically meaningless statements to a complete beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your while condition will continue forever because you never `break` out of it.  But you do not need do in this case just change

```
while(true)
     if (choice.equals("enter building"))
          System.out.println("You have entered the empty building");

     else 
          System.out.println("You are now in the street with a dead body lying around drawned in blood \n there is a building right infront of you\n What would you like to do?");
```

to

```
while(choice.equals("some invalid choice"))
{
    choice = input.nextLine();
}
```

or

```
while(!choice.equals("some valid choice"))
{
    choice = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: This wasn't quit the solution, but it made me come up with it.

Comment: @user2628367 Well I am glad it worked for you :) thanks for accepting

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation, do-while loop I would suggest to use, where first time question you have to ask and later on decision is based on choice

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice=null;

do{

 System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
 choice = input.nextLine();


}while(!choice.equals("enter building"));
```

I am not sure on your exact requirement, so jumbled condition as per need, but I think approach should be of do-while here.

In your case, there is no breaking condition mentioned for `while(true){ //Infinite loop }` that is why it going infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("You are now...");
    String choice = Scanner.nextLine();
    if (choice.equals("enter building")) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never change the value of choice within the loop. Essentially once they make a choice they must make that choice forever.

```
choice = input.nextLine();
```

Plus your loop will happen indefinitely because it is always true. You may break in order to exit the loop or have a variable to determine your state.

```
int state = 1;
while(state == 1) {
    choice = input.nextLine();
    if(choice.equals("leave")) {
        state = 2;
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

Every good game has state and some kind of finite state machine.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
        String choice = input.nextLine();
    while(true)
        if (choice.equals("enter building"))
            System.out.println("You have entered the empty building");

        else 
            System.out.println("You are now in the street with a dead body lying around drawned in blood \n there is a building right infront of you\n What would you like to do?");
```

with

```
while(!input.nextLine().equals("enter building")){
        System.out.println("You are now in the street with a dead body on the floor drowned in blood \n there is a building right ahead of you\n What would you like to do?");
    }
```